# Html form with 3 columns

Tags: html

I am looking at creating form with 4 columns like

```
Name Phone City Remarks

<html>
  <body>
<form id="myform" action="/" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="mytext" />
  <input type="text" name="Phone number" id="mytext" />
  <input type="text" name="City" id="mytext" />
  <input type="text" name="remarks" id="mytext" />
  <input type="submit" id="mysubmit" />
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the code I have they look to be having separated.. I want like form/grid can you please let me know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a table

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Column 1</td>
<td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thankq can you tell me this syntax in a form

Comment: put the table inside the form or the form inside the table, it doesn't particularly matter.

Answer (score 0):

Inside form you can use html table, tr and td tags to achieve the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `column-count` property:

```
#myform {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
}​
```

Example is here - http://jsfiddle.net/4yVGb/

OR

Make another markup inside of the form